# Clear the DataGridView without loosing the source

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a form with DataGridView, dataSourced by dataTable. When i insert the record at the end i press the Clear button or form all fields (textboxes, comboboxes, DGV checkboxes) get cleared automatically when i press the save button.

I normally clear the textboxes and comboboxes by writing:

```
textbox1.text = ""
combobox1.text = ""
```

but when i do clear DGV with this like:

```
dgvPurchase.dataSource = nothing
dgvPurchase.Refresh()
```

or
    dgvPurchase.rows.clear()

It does clear the DGV but when i add new entry so DataGridView and data both do not appear into DGV. On the Form Load event I have the following code:

```
dtField = retrieveFull("ProductBasicInfo")

cmbPurProdID.DisplayMember = "ProdName"
    cmbPurProdID.ValueMember = "ProdID"
    cmbPurProdID.DataSource = dtField


 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("ProdID")
 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("ProdName")
 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("RetailerID")
 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("RetailerName")
 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("UnitPrice")
 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("Qty")
 dtPurchase.Columns.Add("Amount")

 dgvPurchase.DataSource = dtPurchase
```

Please guide me that is there any way that my DataSource do not disturb or if I clear it so it also refresh the DataSource.

This is the add button code, which adds the data into DataGridView

```
 Try

        For a As Integer = 0 To dtPurchase.Rows.Count - 1
            If dtPurchase.Rows(a).Item("ProdID") = cmbPurProdID.SelectedValue Then
                MessageBox.Show("This product is already enlisted")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next


        dRow = dtPurchase.NewRow

        dRow.Item("ProdID") = cmbPurProdID.SelectedValue
        dRow.Item("ProdName") = cmbPurProdID.Text
        dRow.Item("RetailerID") = cmbPurRetailerID.SelectedValue
        dRow.Item("RetailerName") = cmbPurRetailerID.Text
        dRow.Item("UnitPrice") = txtPurUnitPrice.Text.Trim
        dRow.Item("Qty") = txtPurQty.Text.Trim
        dRow.Item("Amount") = txtPurAmount.Text.Trim

       dtPurchase.Rows.Add(dRow)
```

Comment: Set the `datagridview's` `DataSource` to new empty `DataTource`.

Comment: Please add your form's screenshot.

Comment: Fast solution: Put code from `Form.Load` to own method (for example: `LoadData`). Then call this method in `Form.Load` event handler and after you emptying rows...

Comment: @Marek:   I have tried DGV.Datasource = NOthing but not working too. Neolisk   I tried to add an image but i don't know that how i attach image to my thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new empty `DataTable` and set it like this:

c#

```
DataTable emptyDT = new DataTable();
dgvPurchase.DataSource = emptyDT
```

vb.Net

```
Dim emptyDT As New DataTable()
dgvPurchase.DataSource = emptyDT
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: No. It clears the DGV but when i add the new item for next entry so the previous one already residing there.

Comment: Yes it does because you load the previous DataTable into DGV again. And you also do `dtPurchase.Rows.Add(dRow)` which means you are adding the record in previous `DataTable` not to new Empty one. Im also unsure what you are trying to achieve. As you said on  there is button `clear` pressed you would like to clear datagridview and all textboxes without loosing data right? And then when you are adding some records to previous `datatable` `dtPurchase` you would like to display the datagridview with only the new rocord?

Comment: Hmm. Dear Marek I think i'm doing something wrong, if it is true then i am quite unknown with this. Please guide me what changes i make now in my code. I think we are approaching to solution.

Comment: I did something like this.   "dtPurchase.Rows.Clear()". Is it right thing to do?

Comment: @user87 I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve here, may you please describe your desider procedure one more time?

Comment: @ Marek. For your understanding I just want to clear my DataGridView, How do i do it?

Comment: I think you can do `datagridview1.datasource = null;`